# Quickest way to dedupe list in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dict containing lists and need a fast way to dedupe the lists.

I know how to dedupe a list in isolation using the set() function, but in this case I want a fast way of iterating through the dict, deduping each list on the way.

```
hello = {'test1':[2,3,4,2,2,5,6], 'test2':[5,5,8,4,3,3,8,9]}
```

I'd like it to appear like;

```
hello = {'test1':[2,3,4,5,6], 'test2':[5,8,4,3,9]}
```

Though I don't necessarily need to have the original order of the lists preserved.

I've tried using a set like this, but it's not quite correct (it's not iterating properly and I'm losing the first key)

```
for key, value in hello.items(): goodbye = {key: set(value)}
>>> goodbye
{'test2': set([8, 9, 3, 4, 5])}
```

**EDIT**: Following PM 2Ring's comment below, I'm now populating the dict differently to avoid duplicates in the first place. Previously I was using lists, but using sets prevents dupes to be appended by default;

```
>>> my_numbers = {}
>>> my_numbers['first'] = [1,2,2,2,6,5]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> final_list = defaultdict(set)
>>> for n in my_numbers['first']: final_list['test_first'].add(n)
... 
>>> final_list['test_first']
set([1, 2, 5, 6])
```

As you can see, the final output is a deduped set, as required.

Comment: Not interested in preserving order, and also my lists are part of a dict.

Comment: If you don't need to preserve order, then go for a set-based approach: it's more efficient than list-based approaches, but you may not notice much of a speed difference if your lists are small or if they have few dupes. And consider storing sets rather than lists as your dict's values. OTOH, for _very_ small lists, the set-based way may be _slower_. Also, sets use a little more memory than lists.

Comment: @PM2Ring I went with using sets in the end, so avoided dupes in the first place. defaultdict(set) and .add(n) to append to the set did the trick. Q updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not iterating wrong, you're just assigning goodbye as a new dict each time. You need to assign as an empty dict then assign the values to keys in each iteration.

```
goodbye = {}
for key, value in hello.items(): goodbye[key] = set(value)
>>> goodbye
{'test1': set([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), 'test2': set([8, 9, 3, 4, 5])}
```

Also since sets don't preserve order, if you do want to preserve order it's best to make a simple iterating function that will return a new list that skips over already added values.

```
def uniqueList(li):
    newList = []
    for x in li:
        if x not in newList:
            newList.append(x)
    return newList


goodbye = {}
for key, value in hello.items(): goodbye[key] = uniqueList(value)
>>> goodbye
{'test1': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'test2': [5, 8, 4, 3, 9]}
```

Comment: I guess that's one of the reasons OP said that his solution is "not quite correct", and order is preserved in the lists (!) in the expected output.

Comment: OP here. Actually, preserving the order doesn't matter. So this approach works fine for my purposes as well. My solution wasn't quite correct because I was assigning a new value instead of appending, leaving myself with only one key.

Comment: Added a second order preserving solution anyway, for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a list comprehension with a [`deduplicate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order) function that preserves the order:

```
def deduplicate(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [ x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]

{key: deduplicate(value) for key, value in hello.items()}
```

Comment: Just as a note: dict comprehensions don't work with older Python versions like 2.7.

Comment: @Daniel it works in Python 2.7 , it does not work in any version older than that.

Comment: @AnandSKumar You're right. I messed that up.

Comment: I'm on 2.7.10 and this approach works great. Thanks.The main advantage over assigning the values as set() (in the other answer) is that this keeps them as a list, and also retains the original order, is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>>hello = {'test1':[2,3,4,2,2,5,6], 'test2':[5,5,8,4,3,3,8,9]}    
>>>for key,value in hello.iteritems():
       hello[key] = list(set(value))
>>>hello
{'test1': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'test2': [8, 9, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: Ah cool, that turns the 'set' back into a list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more verbose way of doing it, which preserves order and works in all Python versions:

```
for key in hello:
    s = set()
    l = []
    for subval in hello[key]:
        if subval not in s:
            l.append(subval)
            s.add(subval)
    hello[key] = l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,9,10]
seen = set()
print list(filter(lambda x:x not in seen and not seen.add(x),my_list))
```